# AndroidPlot null pointer exception, Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, androidplot

I was given this error in the google play console:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    1. at com.androidplot.Plot$BufferedCanvas.recycle (Plot.java:225)
    2. at com.androidplot.Plot$1.run (Plot.java:407)
    3. at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

can someone explain why this is happening and suggest how I could fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: You seem be trying to call a method on `null` (for example `null.getName()`). That causes a `NullPointerException()`. Try to debug your code and put breakpoints before the error occurence to minimize the error frame and finally find the variable that is causing this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I've managed to stop it crashing but the main cause of the problem is that the androidPlot graph doesn't show/load on devices with API23 or lower which still exists. Do you know what would cause this on some API's but not others?

Comment: No sorry, I'm not that familiar with android development nor the API you are using.